# How to derive parameters from a lambda expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

How can I change my template function definition so that it will work?

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <functional>

using namespace std;

void callthis(function<void()> func){
    func();
}

void callthis(function<void(int)> func, int par){
    func(par);
}


template<typename... Args>
void callthistemp(function<void(Args...)> func, Args&&... args){
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main(){

callthis([](){cout << "hello " << endl;}); // (1)
callthis([](int x)->void{cout << "hello " << x << endl;},1); //(2)
function<void(int)> xx = [](int x){cout << "hello" << endl;};
callthistemp(xx,1);//(3)

//callthistemp([](int x)->void{cout << "hello" << endl;},1); //(4)
//callthistemp<int>([](int x)->void{cout << "hello" << endl;},1); //(5)
}
```

The first three cases all works well, but the last two do not compile, and gives the error

```
lambdatemplate.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
lambdatemplate.cpp:29:66: error: no matching function for call to ‘callthistemp(main()::__lambda3, int)’
     callthistemp<int>([](int x)->void{cout << "hello" << endl;},1); //(5)
                                                                  ^
lambdatemplate.cpp:29:66: note: candidate is:
lambdatemplate.cpp:17:6: note: template<class ... Args> void callthistemp(std::function<void(Args ...)>, Args&& ...)
 void callthistemp(function<void(Args...)> func, Args&&... args){
      ^
lambdatemplate.cpp:17:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
lambdatemplate.cpp:29:66: note:   ‘main()::__lambda3’ is not derived from ‘std::function<void(Args ...)>’
     callthistemp<int>([](int x)->void{cout << "hello" << endl;},1); //(5)
```

Comment: It's not a compiler issue.

Comment: @Puppy, it seems like to me that the definition of lambda fixed definition of the function at compile time. Why, logistically, couldn't the compiler figure out the correct signature of lambda and convert it to the right function type, then infer the template from it? It seems doable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
template<typename L, typename... Args>
void callthistemp(L const &func, Args&&... args)
{
  func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

There is no need to wrap your lambda into a (sometimes expensive) std::function when using templates.
(expensive means that it may use heap allocations which is not necessary in this case).

Comment: I had to downvote you for "expensive". Never heard of SBO? You just made it *worse*.

Comment: @Puppy: I changed the answer to explain what I mean by writing "expensive".

Comment: @RudigerStevens: It's still just bad and wrong. Have you got a single shred of evidence to suggest that this is in a hot path that merits caring about a dynamic allocation? Your whole answer is just "Fix your code by not fixing at all for no reason at all."

Comment: @peppe: Sure it is: His question was "How can I change my template function definition so that it will work? ". And that's what is answered by me.

Comment: @Puppy: As there is a solution which is a) not more complicated and b) avoids potential heap allocations, why not change it no matter if in a hot path or not?

Comment: It's not a solution because it doesn't solve the problem of the OP's lack of understanding as to why his current code fails. Both a) and b) are irrelevant.

Comment: @Puppy: We are not here to judge the OPs abilities but just answer his question.

Comment: This is the correct answer. OP doesn't really need L to be an std::function, just something which can be treated as a function and this is the right way to do it.

Comment: But **WHY** doesn't OP's code work? I agree that this is a more generic and better solution and everything. Can anyone instead *explain what's wrong with OP's code?*

Answer (score 1):

A lambda is not a std::function for any template arguments. This is why there is a problem. The compiler note says it all.

```
main()::__lambda3’ is not derived from ‘std::function<void(Args ...)>’
```

This is what would be required for the call to work. You will have to construct a temporary or perhaps create a `make_function` kind of thing. The first three work because you are not trying to pass a lambda as a templated std::function.